# can a VPN provider do DNS poisoning?

Tags: vpn, man-in-the-middle, dns, dns-spoofing

I was wondering if we push our DNS over the VPN and basically let them do DNS resolution, is it possible to perform DNS poisoning and man in the middle attack on us?
I know browsers check certificates but is there any other security layer that prevents a VPN provider to do that?

Comment: Do you need another security layer other than PKI TLS certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use plaintext UDP for DNS queries, then nothing prevents the VPN from forging the response. However, this is only a problem for plaintext protocols like HTTP which are vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, anyway. When you use HTTPS, then forged DNS responses can only be used to block access to the target site. It's not possible to perform a man-in-the-middle attack due to the certificate check, as you already stated.

Additionally, you can make DNS requests over TLS (DoT) or HTTPS (DoH) to prevent forged DNS responses.

Comment: DoT and DoH in themselves are equally unsafe - you just move trust from one party to another. To be completely safe your local resolver must implement DNSSec.

Comment: I disagree with both of your claims. DoT and DoH both do exactly what they were designed for: secure the DNS traffic between the client and a resolver. Since the OP specifically asked about man-in-the-middle attacks by a VPN provider, DoT and DoH are the right tools here. DNSSEC only covers the zones which actually use it, and that's still just a fraction of all zones. Besides that, DNSSEC has its own problems and is definitely not a panacea to “be completely safe”, as you claim.

Comment: You disagree without understanding anything. The resolver company/service/IP can be compromised and DNSSec is the only thing that will allow you to make sure that the IP address (or any other DNS field) you got for your request is valid. DNSSec covers the vast majority of modern high traffic websites. Without DNSSec you're essentially trusting your life on your super duper DoH/DoT provider. Even StackExchange is utilizing DNSSec. I have no "claims" I have facts. Oh God.  I'm sorry, I have a feeling of disgust, so I'll just walk away. "Claims". What the hell.

Comment: I have no idea why you're so angry, but if you want to preach or sell something rather than have a reasonable discussion, this might not be the best community for you. You will definitely get counter-arguments when your claims are nonsense.

Comment: Interesting discussion you guys are having.  @ArtemS.Tashkinov,  With regard to DNSSEC - if the registrar that the domain is registered with (e,g. GoDaddy), or the TLD (e.g. Verisign, for .com), or the root (e.g. ICANN) were to 'go rogue', couldn't any one of these entities take over the DNS for the domian, and serve bogus DNS records that appear to be perfectly authentic via DNSSEC?  If so, are we not simply shifting our trust from DNS providers (and possibly CAs for those that want to use DNSSEC instead of CA's for SSL authenticity) to these entities?

Comment: To be 'completely safe', we need a decentralized trustless model (like TOR uses), but most people prefer names like nytimes.com to nytimesn7cgmftshazwhfgzm37qxb44r64ytbb2dj3x62d2lljsciiyd.onion, so we'll always be stuck with trusting someone.

Comment: @mti2935 that's a good question, I'm half asleep to think about it right now. Maybe you could ask a question and we could discuss it publicly as a new problem, not here in the comments section.

Comment: @Ja1024 which of my claims "are nonsense" exactly? I stand for everything I said. If you have a DoH/DoT resolver (I mean a remote DNS company/IP) and your trust them without using DNSSec, the said resolver can feed you absolutely anything which is no different from not having DoH/DoT at all. DoH/DoT do not prevent forged responses, they just don't allow MiTM for your DNS queries.

Comment: First off, if the client uses HTTPS, then forging DNS responses doesn't get an attacker anywhere. They can hand out wrong IP addresses all day long -- as long as none of the hosts is able to present a valid certificate for the domain, the handshake immediately fails, so the client knows there's a problem and can simply switch to a proper DNS resolver. If the client uses plaintext HTTP, then having DNSSEC-verified DNS responses addresses is completely useless, because an attacker can still forge the *traffic* between client and server -- and that's what matters.

Comment: Secondly, DNSSEC doesn’t magically solve the problem of trust. If you accept a complete DNSSEC chain of trust, that means you have to trust the ICANN, Verisign, various TLD operators and everybody else who happens to be within the chain of trust for a particular domain. Third, DNSSEC still relies on 2048-bit RSA (or 1024-bit RSA until 2016) for the root zone ZKS. Depending on your level of paranoia, this may be “good enough”, but it’s not nearly state-of-the-art.

Comment: And fourth, the Internet isn't nearly as enthusiastic about DNSSEC as you are. Adoption has gotten better, but it's no universally accepted solution, so there are plenty of gaps, i.e. domains which aren't covered at all.